# KeyListener not recognized

Tags: java, swing, compilation

I'm having trouble adding a keylistener to my jframe.

My KeyTester class implements KeyListener, and my Window class implements JFrame, but my KeyTester isn't recognized as a KeyListener.

```
public class KeyTester implements KeyListener
public class Window extends JFrame
w.addKeyListener(new KeyTester());
```

Above, w is a Window. This results in this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method addKeyListener(KeyListener) in the type Component is not applicable for the arguments (KeyTester)
```

And when I use `w.addKeyListener((KeyListener) new KeyTester());`

It results in this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: testers.KeyTester cannot be cast to java.awt.event.KeyListener
```

Please help, I have another project set up just like this and it works fine.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Regardless of the issue, you should avoid using `KeyListener` and instead use the Key Bindings API, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, sorry. It works for me... I think I don't really have to mention it another time, but please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)